# Concurrent Requests to Express JS fails. Need Explanation what is happening

Tags: node.js, express, concurrency, axios, aws-fargate

Hi I have an expressjs server running on AWS Fargate that handles many API calls to different services and aggregates them to a single response back to the client.

My problem is that, I have found that when I have requests to the same endpoint coming in at around the same time, at least one of these requests will fail. The behavior has been very weird and so I'd like a little help explaining what is happening and hopefully how to fix this.

To start this is a pseudo code of how my route is setup:

```js
router.post( '/endpoint', async function (req, res, next) {
  try {
    let uId = req.body.uId
    let logId = req.body.logId

    let user = await axios(uId) //call to database to retrieve user information (appsync)
    console.log(logId, user)

    let data = []

    for (i = 0, i<user.accounts.length, i++) {
      if (user.accounts[i].provider === 'google') {
        let googleInfo = await axios(user.accounts[i]) // calls google API 
        console.log(logId, user.accounts[i], i , googleInfo)
        data.push(googleInfo)

      } else if (user.accounts[i].provider === 'microsoft') {
        let microsoftInfo = await axios(user.accounts[i]) // calls microsoft graph API
        console.log(logId, user.accounts[i], i , microsoftInfo)
        data.push(microsoftInfo)

      }
    }

    let response = processDataFunction(data) // some function that processes the data

    res.json(response)
  } catch (e) {
    next(e)
  }
})
```

This all works normally when there is only one request. However, when 2 or more are going to our endpoint at the same time, the server responds with a 500 server error and this thing is what I see in my cloudwatch logs.

```
dateTime1: request1, user: {}
dateTime2: request1, user.accounts[0], 0, googleInfo: {user.accounts[0]}
dateTime3: request1, user.accounts[1], 1, microsoftInfo: {user.accounts[1]}
dateTime4: request1, user.accounts[2], 2, googleInfo: {user.accounts[3]}
dateTime5: error ......
dateTime6: request2, user.accounts[0], 0, googleInfo: {user.accounts[0]}
dateTime7: request2, user.accounts[1], 1, microsoftInfo: {user.accounts[1]}
dateTime8: request2, user.accounts[2], 2, googleInfo: {user.accounts[2]}
dateTime9: request2, user.accounts[3], 3, googleInfo: {user.accounts[3]}
```

The error is caused by the microsoft/google server erroring out because I am requesting resources for `user.accounts[3]`, when the loop and the access token is still in `user.accounts[2]` (see dateTime4)

I was able to partially fix this by raising the number of running tasks in ECS. I ended up being able to have more concurrent requests at the same time. However, at a certain point the same errors would still occur.

Any explanation why this is happening and is my only fix to raise the number of ECS tasks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To anyone that encounters this same problem. I still don't know what is happening but I was able to fix this by turning all my for loops into:

```js
Promise.all(arr.map( async(item) => { 
  return await axios( // request )
}))
```